# Google map crash android 14 Jetpack compose?

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, google-maps-android-api-2, jetpack-compose-map

I just migrated my code to SDK 34 and Jeptpack compose version 1.5.4 and material3 v = 1.1.2 also com.google.gms:google-services:4.4.0 but I am getting crash when opening Google map which was working fine before.

Crash message is:

```
android.net.ConnectivityManager$TooManyRequestsException
                                                                                                        at android.net.ConnectivityManager.convertServiceException(ConnectivityManager.java:4165)
                                                                                                        at android.net.ConnectivityManager.sendRequestForNetwork(ConnectivityManager.java:4357)
                                                                                                        at android.net.ConnectivityManager.sendRequestForNetwork(ConnectivityManager.java:4364)
                                                                                                        at android.net.ConnectivityManager.registerNetworkCallback(ConnectivityManager.java:4746)
                                                                                                        at android.net.ConnectivityManager.registerNetworkCallback(ConnectivityManager.java:4716)
                                                                                                        at m.ewx.h(:com.google.android.gms.policy_maps_core_dynamite@233610105@233610102065.573949206.573949206:41)
                                                                                                        at m.ewx.<init>(:com.google.android.gms.policy_maps_core_dynamite@233610105@233610102065.573949206.573949206:140)
                                                                                                        at com.google.maps.api.android.lib6.impl.hz.<init>(:com.google.android.gms.policy_maps_core_dynamite@233610105@233610102065.573949206.573949206:7)
                                                                                                        at com.google.android.gms.maps.internal.CreatorImpl.c(:com.google.android.gms.policy_maps_core_dynamite@233610105@233610102065.573949206.573949206:1094)
                                                                                                        at com.google.android.gms.maps.internal.CreatorImpl.logInitialization(:com.google.android.gms.policy_maps_core_dynamite@233610105@233610102065.573949206.573949206:16)
                                                                                                        at com.google.android.gms.maps.internal.i.bp(:com.google.android.gms.policy_maps_core_dynamite@233610105@233610102065.573949206.573949206:75)
                                                                                                        at m.bbf.onTransact(:com.google.android.gms.policy_maps_core_dynamite@233610105@233610102065.573949206.573949206:21)
                                                                                                        at android.os.Binder.transact(Binder.java:1183)
                                                                                                        at com.google.android.gms.internal.maps.zza.zzc(com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps@@18.2.0:2)
                                                                                                        at com.google.android.gms.maps.internal.zze.zzl(com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps@@18.2.0:4)
                                                                                                        at com.google.android.gms.maps.MapsInitializer.initialize(com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps@@18.2.0:12)
                                                                                                        at com.google.android.gms.maps.MapsInitializer.initialize(com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps@@18.2.0:1)
                                                                                                        at com.google.android.gms.maps.zzai.zzb(com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps@@18.2.0:2)
                                                                                                        at com.google.android.gms.maps.zzai.createDelegate(com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps@@18.2.0:1)
                                                                                                        at com.google.android.gms.dynamic.DeferredLifecycleHelper.zaf(com.google.android.gms:play-services-base@@18.1.0:6)
                                                                                                        at com.google.android.gms.dynamic.DeferredLifecycleHelper.onCreate(com.google.android.gms:play-services-base@@18.1.0:1)
                                                                                                        at com.google.android.gms.maps.MapView.onCreate(com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps@@18.2.0:4)
                                                                                                        at com.google.maps.android.compose.GoogleMapKt.lifecycleObserver$lambda$11(GoogleMap.kt:207)
                                                                                                        at com.google.maps.android.compose.GoogleMapKt.$r8$lambda$Vm6abttjyrD0BNPAw0a-nOgtk1E(Unknown Source:0)
                                                                                                        at com.google.maps.android.compose.GoogleMapKt$$ExternalSyntheticLambda0.onStateChanged(Unknown Source:4)
                                                                                                        at androidx.lifecycle.LifecycleRegistry$ObserverWithState.dispatchEvent(LifecycleRegistry.kt:314)
                                                                                                        at androidx.lifecycle.LifecycleRegistry.addObserver(LifecycleRegistry.kt:192)
                                                                                                        at com.google.maps.android.compose.GoogleMapKt$MapLifecycle$1.invoke(GoogleMap.kt:182)
                                                                                                        at com.google.maps.android.compose.GoogleMapKt$MapLifecycle$1.invoke(GoogleMap.kt:178)
                                                                                                        at androidx.compose.runtime.DisposableEffectImpl.onRemembered(Effects.kt:82)
                                                                                                        at androidx.compose.runtime.CompositionImpl$RememberEventDispatcher.dispatchRememberObservers(Composition.kt:1137)
                                                                                                        at androidx.compose.runtime.CompositionImpl.applyChangesInLocked(Composition.kt:828)
                                                                                                        at androidx.compose.runtime.CompositionImpl.applyChanges(Composition.kt:849)
                                                                                                        at androidx.compose.runtime.Recomposer.composeInitial$runtime_release(Recomposer.kt:1041)
                                                                                                        at androidx.compose.runtime.ComposerImpl$CompositionContextImpl.composeInitial$runtime_release(Composer.kt:4007)
                                                                                                        at androidx.compose.runtime.ComposerImpl$CompositionContextImpl.composeInitial$runtime_release(Composer.kt:4007)
                                                                                                        at androidx.compose.runtime.CompositionImpl.setContent(Composition.kt:520)
```

Comment: I have faced issue while using Material3 1.1.2. I was not able to load my app it was showing blank.

Comment: Any solution found?

Comment: No, meanwhile you can use M3 1.1.0 or lower version